# NullPointerException on button OnAction

Tags: java, javafx

I am receiving the following error on my JavaFX application:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at restaurant.RestaurantListCell$1.handle(RestaurantListCell.java:123)
at restaurant.RestaurantListCell$1.handle(RestaurantListCell.java:1)
```

The method that causes this error is the following method:

```
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Restaurant item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null)
            setGraphic(null);
        else {
            open = new Button();
            address.setWrappingWidth(250);
            open.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    Parent pane = null;
                    try {
                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../detail/RestaurantDetail.fxml"));
                        DetailController restaurantView = loader.getController();
                        restaurantView.changeInfo(item);
                        pane = loader.load();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                    Scene table = new Scene(pane);
                    Stage x = new Stage();
                    x.setScene(table);
                    x.show();
                }
            });
            setGraphic(box);
        }
    }

}
```

The line that specifically causes it is the restaurantView.changeInfo(item). I have tried hardcoding another restaurant in right above and passing it to the changeInfo() method, but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You call `loader.getController()` before calling `loader.load()`. The controller will not have been created yet, thus `getController()` returns `null`.

Comment: I switched those lines around, but am still getting the error.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `fx:controller` attribute in your FXML file? Is it the same line throwing the NPE?

Comment: I did not have it defined in my FXML file. That fixed my error. Thank you!